# HTTP Digest Authentication with Parameters

Tags: c#

we are trying to connect to a WebService using digest authentication.
It's working fine as long as I don't have any parameters in the uri.
I am searching for a solution since days.

I also tried many examples I found like:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daniem/archive/2013/02/27/digest-authentication-in-system-net-classes-not-compliant-with-rfc2617.aspx

However I always get 401 Not authorized.

See the attached code:

```
private string WebServiceCall(string methodname)
    {
        try
        {
            string response = string.Empty;

            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", servername, port, methodname));
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
            query["fields"] = "posgood";
            builder.Query = query.ToString();
            uri = builder.Uri;

            WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(uri, true);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
            webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
            cache.Add(new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", servername, port, methodname)), "Digest", new NetworkCredential("myUser", "myPassowrd", "Ekahau RTLS Controller"));
            webRequest.Credentials = cache;


            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Exception in WebServiceCall: {0}", caught.Message));
        }
    }
```

If you outcomment the UriBuilder part, it's working fine.
I also tried to use HttpClient.GetAsync() method with the same result.

**EDIT 1:**

Uri without parameters: 172.16.24.51:8550/epe/pos/taglist
 
Uri with parameters: 172.16.24.51:8550/epe/pos/taglist?fields=posgood

Comment: Can you do a quick debug session with and without the UriBuilder part, and then post the two resulting URIs (with query string)? Also, you should record the two attempts in Fiddler and look at the HTTP requests that are sent to the server. See if anything there looks suspicious.

Comment: And one more thought: From what I know, when creating credentials you whould use the host name and not the path to a page (you call it "method"). So try removing the {2} part from cache.Add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found an answer modifying the class from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daniem/archive/2013/02/27/digest-authentication-in-system-net-classes-not-compliant-with-rfc2617.aspx

```
/// <summary>
/// Modified class from:
/// http://blogs.msdn.com/b/daniem/archive/2013/02/27/digest-authentication-in-system-net-classes-not-compliant-with-rfc2617.aspx
/// 
/// Added parameter: opaque
/// Removed parameter: md5, Alogrithm (no md5 algorithm in answer)
/// </summary>
public class DigestHttpWebRequest
{
    private string _user;
    private string _password;
    private string _realm;
    private string _nonce;
    private string _qop;
    private string _cnonce;
    private string _opaque;
    private DateTime _cnonceDate;
    private int _nc;

    private string _requestMethod = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    private string _contentType;
    private byte[] _postData;

    public DigestHttpWebRequest(string user, string password)
    {
        _user = user;
        _password = password;
    }

    public DigestHttpWebRequest(string user, string password, string realm)
    {
        _user = user;
        _password = password;
        _realm = realm;
    }

    public string Method
    {
        get { return _requestMethod; }
        set { _requestMethod = value; }
    }

    public string ContentType
    {
        get { return _contentType; }
        set { _contentType = value; }
    }

    public byte[] PostData
    {
        get { return _postData; }
        set { _postData = value; }
    }

    public HttpWebResponse GetResponse(Uri uri)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        int infiniteLoopCounter = 0;
        int maxNumberAttempts = 2;

        while ((response == null ||
            response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted) &&
            infiniteLoopCounter < maxNumberAttempts)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = CreateHttpWebRequestObject(uri);

                // If we've got a recent Auth header, re-use it!
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cnonce) &&
                    DateTime.Now.Subtract(_cnonceDate).TotalHours < 1.0)
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ComputeDigestHeader(uri));
                }

                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (WebException webException)
                {
                    // Try to fix a 401 exception by adding a Authorization header
                    if (webException.Response != null &&
                        ((HttpWebResponse)webException.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {

                        var wwwAuthenticateHeader = webException.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
                        _realm = GetDigestHeaderAttribute("realm", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                        _nonce = GetDigestHeaderAttribute("nonce", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                        _qop = GetDigestHeaderAttribute("qop", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                        _opaque = GetDigestHeaderAttribute("opaque", wwwAuthenticateHeader);

                        _nc = 0;
                        _cnonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
                        _cnonceDate = DateTime.Now;

                        request = CreateHttpWebRequestObject(uri, true);

                        infiniteLoopCounter++;
                        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw webException;
                    }
                }

                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    case HttpStatusCode.Accepted:
                        return response;
                    case HttpStatusCode.Redirect:
                    case HttpStatusCode.Moved:
                        uri = new Uri(response.Headers["Location"]);

                        // We decrement the loop counter, as there might be a variable number of redirections which we should follow
                        infiniteLoopCounter--;
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Error: Either authentication failed, authorization failed or the resource doesn't exist");
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateHttpWebRequestObject(Uri uri, bool addAuthenticationHeader)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Method = this.Method;

        ///Only for test reason. The Ip is the one for fiddler
        //request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888", true);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType))
        {
            request.ContentType = this.ContentType;
        }

        if (addAuthenticationHeader)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ComputeDigestHeader(uri));
        }

        if (this.PostData != null && this.PostData.Length > 0)
        {
            request.ContentLength = this.PostData.Length;
            Stream postDataStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
            postDataStream.Write(this.PostData, 0, this.PostData.Length); // Send the data.
            postDataStream.Close();
        }
        else if (
            this.Method == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post &&
            (this.PostData == null || this.PostData.Length == 0))
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }

        return request;
    }

    private HttpWebRequest CreateHttpWebRequestObject(Uri uri)
    {
        return CreateHttpWebRequestObject(uri, false);
    }

    private string ComputeDigestHeader(Uri uri)
    {
        _nc = _nc + 1;

        string ha1, ha2;

        ha1 = ComputeMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", _user, _realm, _password));
        ha2 = ComputeMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}", this.Method, uri.PathAndQuery));
        var digestResponse =
            ComputeMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2:00000000}:{3}:{4}:{5}", ha1, _nonce, _nc, _cnonce, _qop, ha2));

        return string.Format("Digest username=\"{0}\",realm=\"{1}\",nonce=\"{2}\",uri=\"{3}\"," +
            "cnonce=\"{7}\",nc={6:00000000},qop={5},response=\"{4}\",opaque=\"{8}\"",
            _user, _realm, _nonce, uri.PathAndQuery, digestResponse, _qop, _nc, _cnonce, _opaque);

        throw new Exception("The digest header could not be generated");
    }

    private string GetDigestHeaderAttribute(string attributeName, string digestAuthHeader)
    {
        var regHeader = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}=""([^""]*)""", attributeName));
        var matchHeader = regHeader.Match(digestAuthHeader);
        if (matchHeader.Success)
            return matchHeader.Groups[1].Value;
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Header {0} not found", attributeName));
    }

    private string ComputeMd5Hash(string input)
    {
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var b in hash)
            sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

A request could look like:

```
private string WebServiceCall(string methodname)
    {
        try
        {
            string response = string.Empty;

            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", _servername, _port, methodname));

            DigestHttpWebRequest req = new DigestHttpWebRequest(_username, _password);

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse(uri))
            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (WebException caught)
        {
            throw new WebException(string.Format("Exception in WebServiceCall: {0}", caught.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception caught)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Exception in WebServiceCall: {0}", caught.Message));
        }
    }
```

I hope this will be helpful to someone, if the other answers won't work.

@christoph: thanks for your help! your tipp with fiddler helped me to find a solution ;)